# Change default ls behaviour on Linux

Tags: linux

By default when I use the command ls on my folder, I have the result sorted by name. What if I want to change that behavior system wide for created_at ?

Comment: Sorry. bu this is a place to ask _programming related questions_.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 11):

Edit the file `~/.bashrc` in your favorite text editor and add the following line at the bottom:

```
alias ls='ls -tU'
```

Save and close the file.

The next time you open a terminal, `ls` will give the list in sorted order of time.
But if you need to make it take effect immediately, you can:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

I will brutally chop your question in two:

1. How to sort by creation time:
   There may not be an answer to that. This post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created seems to suggest that the creation date is *NOT* stored in many Unix systems, but I'm not sure about linux. Also, ls in MacOS *IS* able to sort by creation date. If you have a mac, do `ls -tU`
2. How to change a command's default behavior:
   Suppose that you have found a way to make ls sort by creation date (for example, on MacOS, I do so by typing in `ls -tU`), then you could use the alias command. Simply do `alias ls='ls -tU'` and in the future all ls commands would be replaced by `ls -tu`. This solution persists until your close your terminal window, but you can always add it to a startup script (for example, `.bashrc`) to apply it every time you pull up your command shell.